# Multi-use and use-Type field vs. A field per any use

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-design

I have a table for some uses like this example:

A table for objects named `tblObject` that needs to store some properties; So, I can use one of these solutions:

1. Add a field for each property and with its own data type.
2. Just add one field of foreign key that related to below model that in `tblObjProp` I need another field for storing variant values:

```
+-----------+         +------------+         +-------------+
| tblObject | 1-----* | tblObjProp | *-----1 | tblProperty |
+-----------+         +------------+         +-------------+
```

---

I think using this solutions is based on properties count, As I don't know the count, I need to have a reference like a recommendation in this site to identify that count or any other recommendation.

And also I need some recommendation for data type of `value` field in `tblObjProp` that in SQL I have `sql_variant` or `nvarchar(max)` or etc.

If answers are related to RDBMS, I need that for *SQL Server 2012* and *Oracle 11g*.

---

If I have a table like `Person` with columns `Id, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, Comments, NID, ...` there is a choice for each column:

- Make it static in the `Person` table.
- Add it to `tblProperty`.

That I want to know I should always select the second choice or for example for `Comments` or `NID` first choice is better?

Comment: This is the EAV pattern (anti-pattern, as many will say). There is plenty of material out there about its pros and cons. What you will probably discover is that in trying to reinvent the wheel, you'll have to forego most of the power of the relational database and deliver a solution that performs poorly for the even most simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the number of properties, and this number doesn't change very often, then i would go for solution 1 as this allows correct indexing of the fields (and to my mind is correct database design).

But if the number of properties can vary for each row, and properties are added frequently, then i have seen solution 2 (google "key-value pair"). The downside when you get a large number (millions in my experience) of items to which you hold properties, this solution becomes very slow.